# Understanding mzML, specifically precursor mass

Tags: reference-request, mass-spectrometry

I'm a Biotechnologist and computer scientist, migrating into the field of Mass Spec. for my new position. Some things I know well, and others not at all. Please be patient :)

I'm working with OpenMS, Python, MGF and mzML files.

Q1: Is there a better resource for understanding the format of mzML files than [PeptideAtlas specifications](http://www.peptideatlas.org/tmp/mzML1.1.0.html)?

Q2: In the MGF specification you get a listing of the precursor protein mass (PEPMASS) followed by a list of ions in m/z format.

Is the precursor (protein) mass listed similarly in the mzML file? Is it the BPI in (for example)

```
      <cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000796" name="spectrum title" value="runID:160812_29,index:2120,ID:controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=2121,path:160812_29.raw,scan:2121,activation:HCD,isolation:745.306640625,selectedIon:745.306640625,z:2,precursorScan:controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=2118,spectrum:MSn spectrum,MSlevel:2,scanstartmin:7.4891189999999996,scanstartsec:449.34713999999997,BPmz:745.4205487,BPI:15730.942999999999,TIC:54362.472999999998"/>
```

EDIT:
This is what I have so far:

In the  tag, we have...

```
<cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000796" name="spectrum title" value="runID:160812_29,index:2060,ID:controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=2061,path:160812_29.raw,scan:2061,activation:HCD,isolation:555.730041503906,selectedIon:555.730059736802,z:2,precursorScan:controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=2060,spectrum:MSn spectrum,MSlevel:2,scanstartmin:7.3208402000000001,scanstartsec:439.25041199999998,BPmz:129.1023507,BPI:17504.615000000002,TIC:1.8637816e05"/>
```

We have ...

```
selectedIon:555.730059736802,z:2,precursorScan:controllerType=0 controllerNumber=1 scan=2060,
```

...followed by...

```
<cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000500" name="scan window upper limit" value="1155.0" unitCvRef="MS" unitAccession="MS:1000040" unitName="m/z"/>
```

...implying the upper limit is roughly the Precurser mass.

Later we find, in the (of course) precursorList count="1" tag, subtag selectedIonList count="1"  the double the above mass, with a charge count of 2...

```
<cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000744" name="selected ion m/z" value="555.730059736802" unitCvRef="MS" unitAccession="MS:1000040" unitName="m/z"/>
<cvParam cvRef="MS" accession="MS:1000041" name="charge state" value="2"/>
```

All of this together indicates that precursor mass is ~550 x 2 = 1110.

I can't find any more direct route to this discovery than the deduction.

Is this correct and is it the best route?

[image]

Comment: You are calculating the precursor _ion_ mass, which is not the same as the peptide neutral mass.  Most peptides probably ionize as $\ce{(M + nH)^{n+}}$ but that is an assumption.  mzML has to handle small-molecule spectra as well, where things like $\ce{(M + Na)+}$ happen a lot.

Comment: Also unfortunately most vendors do not fully adhere to formal mzML specifications in their converters.  I'm suspicious that the `scan window upper limit` tag is just an upper limit and not related to any detected ions in any way.